# Running Excel Macro from Python 3.8

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32

Im trying to run a macro from python 3.8.

The macro itself is not the problem, if i run it directly from excel works fine.

The problem is that the Python code does not achieve to open the workbook and execute the macro.
Its is very importat that the excel application is not visible while executing the macro.

The code is the following:

from **future** import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
            def test_excel_macro(self):
                try:
                    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

```
                xlsPath = os.path.expanduser(r'G:\folder\foolder...\Cuadros Monitor.xlsm')
                xlApp.Application.visible = False
                xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath, readonly=1)
                xlApp.Run('MacroName')
                xlApp.Workbooks.Close(SaveChanges=1)
                xlApp.Quit()

            except:
                xlApp.Quit()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
         unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you delete the `except` block, do any exceptions appear?

Comment: I added a print() in the except block, right now the code is going to the exception

Comment: Ok. The next step is to determine the details of the exception. The easiest way to do that is to delete the except block and view the stack trace that appears when the program crashes.